# Prevent hidden files embedded in images from being uploaded to server

Tags: php, hidden-files

I've noticed that it is possible to store hidden files within JPG/GIF/PNG images, which could include illegal images or collections of them in .rar format. Users may exploit this to upload and share illicit content amongst themselves on seemingly average images to the naked eye, on any website that allows image uploading.

I could not find any source on the internet that deals with having PHP prevent image files from containing other files inside of them, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction. The following is not enough to detect additional content within a file, as the exif will still be a match to the file's extension:

```
if (exif_imagetype($imagefile['tmp_name']), IMAGETYPE_GIF) { //code; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but perhaps creating a new image using the GD / Imagemagick commands could strip out the extra hidden data.

Comment: great suggestion. I will test it and report back.